# How to get around "Binary was not built with debug information"?

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, debugging, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to debug a C DLL that I'm using with a Delphi program.  I built the DLL with Visual C++, with debug information enabled.  I built the Delphi program with Delphi 2009, with debug information enabled.  But apparently they use different formats, because when I try to attach the VC++ debugger to my program, it says "binary was not built with debug information" and won't even accept as valid the breakpoints I put in the C code, which *was* built with debug info in the format VC++ understands.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "won't accept as valid" the debug breakpoints in the C code what do you mean exactly? Does it not enable them? If so has the DLL been loaded yet when you set the breakpoints? I find it can simplify matters if I wait to set the breakpoints until after I'm sure the DLL in question has been loaded. If this is not what is happening, please elaborate on what you mean by "valid" breakpoints.

Other options are to set function breakpoints, or the compile the DLL with strategically placed [`DebugBreak()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297.aspx) calls.

Are you sure it's the right DLL that's being loaded (i.e. the debug version)?. Again, even the right DLL is being loaded I'm not sure the error is necessarily applying to the DLL and not just the main executable. Or it could be having problems loading the symbol database as suggested by jdigital, assuming you extract them out for debug builds of your DLL. Even with no debugging symbols, debugging should still be feasible, especially since it's a DLL, you can work from the exported symbols.

This isn't a COM component is it? If it is, I'd double check that the debug version was the one registered before you start up your process.

Again I'd still be interested in hearing exactly what happens when you try to set a break point. If you go to the breakpoints window in VS it should clarify why the breakpoint couldn't be set, if that's what is happening.

Hmm. I don't have much experience with `/Z7`, do you still have the .obj file for the DLL? The docs seem to imply that's necessary for debugging. Alternatively I'd try building with `/Zi` instead and getting a .pdb for that sucker.

Comment: Yeah, it's been loaded.  I may have to rebuild it with DebugBreak calls, though I'm not sure how well that will work since it doesn't recognize that there's debug information available.

Comment: Re: your edit:  "This breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document."  This is not a COM DLL, and it's the exact same one that came out of the build process.  I even moved the EXE to the DLL's output folder. It was built with the /Z7 debug info option.

Answer (score 1):

Debug formats are not standardised - basically you can't use Delphi to debug MS compiled code or vice versa.

You can debug Delphi DLLs in Delphi and you can use those DLLs with other apps not compiled with Delphi, provided you mark the Delphi functions for export. What you can't do is debug those DLLs symbolically in a 3rd party debugger, which would have to understand Object Pascal name mangling at the very least.

Comment: I'm trying to use VS to debug VS-compiled code.  The Delphi app is irrelevant, or at least it ought to be.  I know I've been able to debug Delphi DLLs used in non-Delphi programs before...

Comment: Apparently the DLL app being in Delphi *is* relevant, since the first two tags you used were delphi and delphi2009. :-)

Comment: Neil:  Go back and read the post again.  What I'm trying to do is debug a DLL--compiled in Visual Studio--in Visual Studio.  Thing is, you can't debug a DLL without an app attached to it.  Only the app is in Delphi. But I'm not trying to debug the Delphi app.  Just the DLL compiled in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Visual C++ (don't have it installed at all anymore), but maybe this will help...

If you were writing a DLL in Delphi and using it from C++, and you wanted to debug the DLL, you'd open the source for the DLL in *Delphi* and set a breakpoint. You'd then use Run|Parameters and set the C++ application as the host executable and hit run in the Delphi IDE. The IDE would then launch the C++ application and run it as usual until the breakpoint in the DLL was hit, and then would break as you'd expect.

Is something similar available in VC++? (You didn't say which version of VC++, or which version of Visual Studio or the earlier IDE you were using.)

If not, the only alternative I could think of is to do a quick VC++ app that uses the DLL and debug via that instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I was trying to do.  It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thats exactly what i do in my current project. Under Solution options-debugging-Command, i put my delphi host application and can debug my dll. And the other way round (debugging the delphi app) works as well. the only thing not possible (at least for me) is to step into the c++dll from the application or the other way round, so i can only debug one of these two per try

Answer (score 0):

Have you pointed the debugger at the symbols for your DLL?  If there's any doubt, try running with [Filemon](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to see if the debugger is failing when it tries to load the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Insure that is opening the DLL in the Debug Folder, not another one in some other folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ten years later and this is happening to me, while debugging a custom DLL used in Team Developer, setting debugging command to start the Team Developer IDE.  The objective is to step through the 3rd party code to the point of invocation of an exported function from the DLL.

Starting the debugger launches the IDE without error, but running the TD project within the TD IDE causes an exception in VS on a DLL used by the TD IDE.

How do I ignore the exceptions from outside the project?  Has anyone been able to get around this since '09?